Receiving error when copying files to external APFS drive
I'm trying to copy a film project from external drive A (formatted with ExFAT) to external drive B (formatted with APFS).
This always results in an error message saying: "the item "name" can't be copied because there isn't enough free space".
However, I have now formatted the external drive B multiple times and it's completely empty.
I am assuming that this is happening as I'm trying to copy files from ExFAT to APFS. If this is the case, how can I then do that?

Can you copy files from A to other drives, and from other drives to B?

Are you Finder dragging the film project (you don't specify what sort of project - FinalCut, etc) from A > B? You might find better results if you try a Terminal cp (copy) command instead, and bypass the Finder completely.

Can you get it onto A again formatted as something else [APFS or HFS+]? ExFAT will break FCP projects [& other Mac library-type structures] - see https://www.reddit.com/r/finalcutpro/comments/1c33dz9/why_you_must_never_use_exfatformatted_drives_with/
